# How can you remove cookies from a specific domain, NOT your own

Tags: cookies, cross-domain

we have a unique issue.. it seems one of our payment processors offers additional options to users the first time they visit our payment page with the processor - being sent to it from our website. However, the subsequent times our users go to that payment page, those additional options are gone... we believe it has to do with cookie settings from the site.
Is there a way, with the users interaction/approval, to delete cookies from that other domain BEFORE we direct them to that payment page?? 
So, the process might look something like this:
1) User clicks payment link
2) Confirm box displays notice stating to enable 'these' features, they need to clear their cookies from the site they are being sent to.. 
3) User clicks yes and all cookies from the other domain are deleted
4) User is then directed to the payment page to complete payment with the additional features.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

cookies do not work cross domain, so when your clients go to the payment site, the payment site can not read the cookies that are not set by them

Comment: Yes, I understand.. but, I am talking about cookies set BY the payment companies website.. that exist on the client PC before the go to the site the second time.. is there a way to have the client clear cookies for the payment co. domain.. from within a webapp??

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem of you payment provider and he should solve it! Cookies cannot be read or modified from other domains for security and privacy reasons.

Comment: I agree.. but, they wont! And we are not trying to clear the cookies ourselves.. but to ask the user to initiate the clearing of cookies and then complete it for them, programmatically.